# JQuery does not work inside <ion-view> "IONIC"

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework, owl-carousel

I am facing a weird issue, I want to make jQuery work inside ion-view but I am not able to do so. When I place the div id="owl-demo" outside ion-view it works, so I guess that there is a conflict stopping jQuery to be executed, knowing that when the code is placed inside ion-view, it does not show any errors, just blank, so even I can see what is the error.
Anyone knows why and how I can solve it ?

JQUERY

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
  navigation : true, 
  slideSpeed : 300,
  paginationSpeed : 400,
  singleItem:true
  }); 
});
```

HTML

```
<ion-view>
<ion-content overflow-scroll="true" padding="true" class="has-header">
    <h5 class="heads">DEALS</h5>
    <div ng-controller="Deals">
    <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <div ng-repeat="deal in getDeal"><img style="width: 100%;  height: 100%;" ng-src="{{deal.img}}"></div>
    </div>

    </div>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Well your solution works inside ion-view in browser(chrome). Are u saying this wont work in device?

Comment: Maybe you could be interested in [OWL Carousel integration with AngularJS](http://gik.firetrot.com/index.php/2014/06/24/owl-carousel-integration-with-angularjs/), [angular-owl-carousel directive](https://github.com/jonahbron/angular-owl-carousel) or a discussion with some examples on how to integrate Owl Carousel in AngularJS (https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel/issues/179)

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.loaded", function() {
    // your code
}
```

The ion-view is loaded after document.ready.